# AngularJS: how to pass a url to $http POST

Tags: angularjs, django

I am having trouble with my http POST request in AngularJS. The error I am getting is:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/ 403 (Forbidden). 'rating-add' is a named url
```

So I don't know why it doesn't allow this. This is the template:

```
<script>
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.ratings = [];
    var data = $scope.myForm = {beer_name:'', score:'', notes:'', brewer:''};
    $scope.buttonClick = false;
    $scope.is_clicked = function() {
      $scope.buttonClick=true;
      console.log($scope.buttonClick)
    }
    $scope.submit_to_form = function() {
        $http({
          method: 'POST'
          url: 'rating-add'
          data: data
        });
    }
  })
  </script>
```

And the urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

from ratings.views import home, RatingCreate, delete, edit

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', RatingCreate.as_view(), name='rating-home'),
    url(r'rating/add/$', RatingCreate.as_view(), name='rating-add'),
    url(r'rating/delete/(?P<row_id>[0-9]+)/$', delete , name='rating-delete'),
    url(r'rating/edit/(?P<row_id>[0-9]+)/$', edit , name='rating-edit'),
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to append a leading slash like this -

```
url : '/rating/add'
```

Check out the docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

> You should print out your **routes** from Django to find out where to post.

Comment: That doesn't work because 'rating-add' is a named url.
So /rating-add doesn't match any urlconf.
But even when I try '/rating/add/' I still get the same error.

Comment: Have you tried removing the trailing slash? Or try something like rating/add/1

Comment: Thanks for your help. How do I print my routes?

Comment: check this out https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions
You can use it like this - 
$ ./manage.py show_urls